# Trying to connect a xampp database table to php: errors Undefined variable: mysqli_query and Fatal error

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, xampp

I tried searching a lot about the errors that I'm getting to no avail. I have zero experience with PHP and I got thrown at the task to display an XAMPP Apache database as a table in the browser. The programmer heading me has a week long vacation so I am looking for help.

this is the code for the connection to the database:

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','', 'csvdb6');
// mysql_select_db('csvdb6');
if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
echo "Success: A proper connection to MySQL was made! The my_db database is great." . PHP_EOL;
echo "Host information: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

and this is the php code to be displayed in the browser:

```
<?php
include_once('db_connection.php');
$query="select* from pmid";
$result= $mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$query);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Table with database</title>
<style>
table {
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
color: #588c7e;
font-family: monospace;
font-size: 25px;
text-align: left;
}
th {
background-color: #588c7e;
color: white;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
<th>PMID</th>
<th>ResearchGroup</th>
<th>Species</th>
<th>Method</th>
</tr>
<?php
$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
//review below code line
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "", "csvdb6");
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql = "SELECT PMID, ResearchGroup, Species, Method FROM pmid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<tr><td>" . $row["PMID"]. "</td><td>" . $row["ResearchGroup"] . "</td><td>"
. $row["Species"]. "</td></tr>" . $row["Method"]. "</td><td>";
}
echo "</table>";
} else { echo "0 results"; }
$conn->close();
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

The errors I now got are the following:

> Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli_query in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\testing2.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\testing2.php:4 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown
> in C:\xampp\htdocs\scripts\testing2.php on line 4

I know you guys get a lot of these 'silly questions' and I appreciate any input and your help. Cheers.

Comment: Change `$mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$query);` to `mysqli_query($GLOBALS['link'],$query);`. If you add a `$` in front of it, it will be read as a variable, not a function.

Comment: Also, in your connection code, you close the connection in the end (`mysqli_close($link)`) so you won't be able to use it in the rest of the code without making a new connection.

Comment: You're also then making a new connection further down in your code, using the old (and since PHP 7 removed) `mysql_*` API, but then you're trying to use that connection as a mysqli connection. `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*` are two completely different API's and can't be mixed.

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to call a variable with the name "$mysqli_query" on line 3 when you remove the dollar sign it will run.